# Prolog, Generate all paths from a node to another, limiting the maximum number of hops

Tags: prolog

my problem: Generate all paths from a node to another, limiting the maximum number of hops

```
node(c(X,Y)):- member(X,[0,1,2,3]),member(Y,[0,1,2,3]).

link(c(X,Y),c(X,YY)) :- node(c(X,Y)), 
            (YY is Y-1; YY is Y+1) ,
            node(c(X,YY)).

link(c(X,Y),c(XX,Y)) :- node(c(X,Y)), 
            (XX is X-1; XX is X+1), 
            node(c(XX,Y)).
```

I have already done this code but, how can i change it to generate all paths from a node to another, limiting the maximum number of hops? Thanks

EDIT:

I want this:

link(c(0,1), 1, X)

And prolog should return this:

X / c(0,0), c(0,2), c(1,1)

And this:

link(c(0,1), 2, X)

And prolog should return this:

X / c(0,0), c(0,2), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,3), c(1,2), c(1,0), c(2,1)

And This:

link(c(0,1), 2, c(2,1))

Return:

Yes

Comment: Please add an example question in prolog and the answer you qould expect.

Comment: Added to my question ^^

Comment: You forgot to add c(0,1) as possible answert to ?- link(c(0,1), 1, X), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to predicates `node/1` and `link/2`, you also need to define the predicate `path/3`.

```
node(c(X,Y)) :-
    member(X, [0,1,2,3]),
    member(Y, [0,1,2,3]).

link(c(X1,Y1), c(X2,Y2)) :-
    node(c(X1,Y1)),
    (   X2 is X1-1, Y2 is Y1
    ;   X2 is X1+1, Y2 is Y1
    ;   X2 is X1, Y2 is Y1-1
    ;   X2 is X1, Y2 is Y1+1 ),
    node(c(X2,Y2)).

% path(+MaxHops, +Start, -End)

path(_, Start, Start).
path(N, Start, End) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    link(Start, Intermediate),
    path(M, Intermediate, End).
```

Some examples:

```
?- path(2,c(0,1),c(2,1)).
true ;
false.

?- path(1, c(0,1), End).
End = c(0, 1) ;
End = c(1, 1) ;
End = c(0, 0) ;
End = c(0, 2) ;
false.

?- path(2,c(0,1), End).
End = c(0, 1) ;
End = c(1, 1) ;
End = c(0, 1) ;  
End = c(2, 1) ;
End = c(1, 0) ;
End = c(1, 2) ; % Eg., there are more than one path that leads from c(0,1) to c(1,2) 
End = c(0, 0) ;
End = c(1, 0) ;
End = c(0, 1) ;
End = c(0, 2) ;
End = c(1, 2) ; % Duplicate answer!
End = c(0, 1) ;
End = c(0, 3) ;
false.

?- distinct(path(2,c(0,1), End)). % eliminate duplicates!
End = c(0, 1) ;
End = c(1, 1) ;
End = c(2, 1) ;
End = c(1, 0) ;
End = c(1, 2) ;
End = c(0, 0) ;
End = c(0, 2) ;
End = c(0, 3) ;
false.
```

To see the path that leads from `Start` to `End`, you can use the following version of the predicate `path/3`:

```
path1(_, Start, [Start]).
path1(N, Start, [Start|Path]) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    link(Start, Intermediate),
    path1(M, Intermediate, Path).
```

Results:

```
?- path1(1, c(0,1), Path).
Path = [c(0, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 0)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 2)] ;
false.

?- path1(2, c(0,1), Path).
Path = [c(0, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1), c(0, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1), c(2, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 0)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 0)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 0), c(1, 0)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 0), c(0, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 2)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 2), c(1, 2)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 2), c(0, 1)] ;
Path = [c(0, 1), c(0, 2), c(0, 3)] ;
false.
```

Comment: My original solution was pretty similar, but I was also unhappy with the repetition. Maybe you should add that in order to use distinct/1, a directive is needed: :- use_module(library(solution_sequences)).

Comment: I think that such directive is not really mandatory, since the ```library(solution_sequences)``` can be autoloaded (at least in SWI-Prolog, which is the compiler I used).

Comment: Yes, you are right! I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
link(Node1, N, Node2):- % there is a path from Node1 to Node2 with N hops at most
    node(Node1),
    node(Node2),
    manhattan_distance(Node1, Node2, M),
    M =< N.

manhattan_distance(c(X1,Y1), c(X2,Y2), M):-
    Dx is abs(X1-X2),
    Dy is abs(Y1-Y2),
    M is Dx+Dy.
```